# Convert string to executable code at run time in c#?

Tags: c#, eval

Is there any way I can convert a string of code into executable code at runtime in c#?

So if I have a file of predicates

```
This is normal text in a txt file
    u => u.Contains("android") && u.Contains("webkit")
    u => u.Contains("iphone") && u.Contains("webkit")
```

I would want to read it in via my program and then capture each predicate as a string and then convert it to code on the fly. Something like:

```
string[] predicates = ///get file contentsa

foreach(var predicate in predicates)
{
       if(userAgent.ConformsTo(eval(predicate))) return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`CSharpCodeProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx) class, but you'll need to build quite a bit of extra code around the snippet, as you have to provide a full class. I did this for my "Snippy" tool for C# in Depth, and you can [download the source](http://csharpindepth.com/Downloads.aspx) to get one simple example of how it can be done.

However, life is becoming much simpler in this area with [Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/roslyn) - you may want to get hold of the [CTP](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=228400) and explore that.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Roslyn ScriptEngine](http://snipd.net/c-code-execution-at-runtime-with-the-microsoft-roslyn-csharp-scriptengine-class).