# Building a LINQ Expression to transate to parentheses in the SQL output

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework 6 and [Waseem Sabjee's solution](http://blog.waseem-sabjee.com/2013/07/23/linq-expression-how-to-append-to-an-expression-at-a-later-stage/) for appending expressions at runtime which works really well.

However, what I can't work out is how to separate parts of the expression with what in SQL would be parentheses.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM SOMETABLE WHERE Field1 = 'somevalue' AND (FIELD2 = 1 OR FIELD2 = 2 OR FIELD2 = 3)
```

instead of

```
SELECT * FROM SOMETABLE WHERE Field1 = 'somevalue' AND FIELD2 = 1 OR FIELD2 = 2 OR FIELD2 = 3
```

> which will output different results and would be wrong in the second
>   example for what I actually want.

(although in SQL I would do the "OR" parts with an "IN" clause)

Normally I'd just put parentheses around the relevant part of the filter but in my case at runtime I don't know how many OR statements I need as I pass in a List of values, the number of which is only known at runtime i.e:

```
public Search(IList<int> vals, string filter){
     Expression<Func<Event, bool>> filter = x => x.Field1 == filter;
     bool first = true;
     for(int i in vals){
         if (first){
             filter = filter.And(x -> x.Field2 == i);
             first = false;
         }
         else{
             filter = filter.Or(x -> x.Field2 == i);
         }
     }
}
```

Does anyone know how this can be achieved with expressions?

Comment: Why couldn't you use `vals.Contains(x.Field2)` ? Wouldn't it be easier? It should generate your **OR** statements automatically

Comment: I don't think that will work Andrey.  A list of contains statements will still just generate separate OR statements that won't be run as one logical part which is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You should create or statements before and statement:

```
public Search(IList<int> vals, string filter){
     Expression<Func<Event, bool>> andFilter = x => x.Field1 == filter;
     var firstVal = vals.First();
     Expression<Func<Event, bool>> orFilter = x=>x.Field2 == firstVal;
     foreach(int i in vals.Skip(1)){
         orFilter = orFilter.Or(x -> x.Field2 == i);         
     }
     andFilter = andFilter.And(orFilter);
}
```

Comment: Hi Kirill, no that won't work. It just rearranges the SQL but without parentheses to get each part to evaluate in the right order i.e. like a BODMAS statement, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

OK so I had to think a bit laterally to solve this as I could not find a way to do this with an expression builder (there may still be a way!)

Instead, I turned to Roslyn that I found [referenced here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321734/convert-string-to-executable-code-at-run-time-in-c).

With Rosyln you can essentially compile strings into C# code and return output to be further used at runtime.

So instead of appending expressions I now create the expression as a piece of code in a string, compile it with Rosyln, and return the new expression I used to filter my data.

This is how it works:

```
ScriptEngine scriptEngine = new ScriptEngine();
string exp = "public System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<my.namespace.object,bool>> CreateFilter(){System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<my.namespace.object,bool>> filter = e => e.Field1.Contains(\"a\");return filter;}CreateFilter();";
```

> This first part sets up the new method as a string.

```
Roslyn.Scripting.Session s = scriptEngine.CreateSession();
s.AddReference(typeof(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression).Assembly);
s.AddReference(typeof(my.namespace.object).Assembly);
```

> You need to add references to any non-system assemblies your code requires just like any other project.

```
Expression<Func<Event, bool>> filter = (Expression<Func<Event, bool>>)s.Execute(exp);
```

> Finally, you just execute the code which returns your new expression.

With this technique you can easily add any parentheses you like, where ever you like, and build up the expression using loops and other conditional statements.

I found Roslyn on NuGet.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my late reply (power issues this side).
Here is my solution (code only)

```
// at this point query will be: SELECT * FROM SOMTABLE WHERE Field1 = 'Cat'
Expression<Func<Event, bool>> filterExpression = x => x.Field1 == filter;

if (vals.Count > 0)
{
    // at this point query will be: SELECT * FROM SOMTABLE WHERE Field1 = 'Cat' AND Field2 = 1
    filterExpression = filterExpression.And(x => x.Field2 == vals.First());
}

if (vals.Count > 1)
{
    // at this point query will be: SELECT * FROM SOMTABLE WHERE Field1 = 'Cat' AND (Field2 = 1 OR Field2 = 3 OR Field2 = 4)
    filterExpression = filterExpression.Or(x => vals.Skip(1).Contains(x.Field2));
}
```

I've posted a link to a vs solution here: http://www.waseem-sabjee.com/code/LinqExpressionFilterIssue.zip